# Asynchronous sockets vs synchronous

Tags: sockets

I have a question about asynchronous sockets. It's been bothering me for the last few months and thought I should wise up and get the facts from the pros here.

I have an incoming stream from a client which I want to take in the data. This incoming stream requires initial setup via strings before it will commence sending the data.

I have heard about the powerful scalability of asynchronous tcp servers like node.js. My question is whether can I use node.js or any other asynchronous tcp server to handshake with this client and receive the incoming stream.

You can think of the incoming data as an stream of stock data or electricity usage at a given point in time. In essence the data will be streaming in continuously.

Pls let me know what other information I need to share to help me understand asynchronous sockets and how to use it.

Comment: If the data will be streamed continously, maybe it's better to use UDP?

Comment: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: It's not possible because the client does not use udp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly normal to have handshaking implemented on top of asynchronous sockets.

Consider the pseudocode:

```
socket = accept() # or connect()
// now socket is connected
socket.write(logon_request)
logon_response = socket.read()
assert(logon_response ok)
// now socket is logged in
socket.write(more_handshake);
handshake_response = socket.read()
assert(handshake_response ok)
// now socket is ready to go

while data = socket.read()
{    process data ... }
```

you can model this as a state machine, which is then easy to use with asynchronous sockets.  See how the code below is analagous to that above, but broken into multiple callbacks:

```
# state Idle -> LoggingOn
handle_connection_event(socket)
    state = LoggingOn
    socket.write(logon_request)

# state LoggingOn -> Handshaking
handle_login_response(socket)
    logon_response = socket.read()
    assert(logon_response ok)
    state = Handshaking
    socket.write(more_handshake);

# state Handshaking -> Ready
handle_handshake_response(socket)
    handshake_response = socket.read()
    assert(handshake_response ok)
    state = Ready
```

and all reads come in here, and get dispatched according to the state machine

```
handle_read(socket)
    switch(state) {
    case LoggingOn: handle_logon_response(socket)
    case Handshaking: handle_handshake_response(socket)
    case Ready: process(socket.read())
    }
```

---

PS. I'm having a major formatting failure here for some reason, hope it's readable

Comment: Thanks! Let me think about yr solution tonight.

Comment: Quick question, can this handle more than one concurrent sockets?

Comment: Yes, as many as you like: this is commonly used with `select`, `poll` or other synchronous event dispatchers. Just associate a separate state machine (and/or callbacks) with each socket.